# maximize partitioned area puzzle....

Tags: calculus, recreational-mathematics, area

I took the time to draw this out.  It's pretty simple and also very chicken scratch.
I apologize for the crudeness and chicken scratch.  The part of this that throws me off is the partitioned part.  So I am wondering if that is something else to more specifically consider with this puzzle?  The puzzle talks about a pig farmer who has a total of 400 ft of electrical fence to create a pig pen for the piggies.  The pig pen will have the feed house on one side of it, so that it will require no use of the fencing material.  Three exterior and two interior fences split the pig pen into three rectangular regions.  The puzzle asks what the dimensions are of the pig pen that will maximize the enclosed area?  What is the maximum area?
[image]
Note.. Dimensions to maximize should be 100 x 200.  It is a little cut off there at the bottom.  Hope the rest is pretty clear even though it is relatively crude.  Again, all apologies!  I am mostly confused with the interior partition and if that is something I need to consider, how would I go about solving that part of the puzzle?  Thank you!

Comment: Nice picture and work! I would think from the problem statement that the two bits you drew in red are also electrical fence and need to come from the $400'$ available, so that you simply start out by writing the area of the rectangle as $x(400-4x)$, not $x(400-2x)$. Do you think that makes sense?

Comment: So, the 4 comes from the number of sections that make up the partitions including the outside panels, since it is an equal rectangle?

Comment: The four in $4x$ comes from the four vertical lines in the part of the figure above the feed house. The $400-4x$ is the length of the horizontal line at the top.

Comment: Nice.  I see.  Thank you fellers.  The Captain is a little less confused.